# Format displayValue option of find function with CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

With CakePHP 3, `displayValue` option allows you to change the field which will be displayed in your view, for example a name instead of an id.

```
find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'no_user', 
    'order' => ['Users.name' => 'asc'],
    'valueField' => ['name']
]);
```

In my example above, I want to display name and first name, but I can't find how to properly use `valueField` to display multiple fields.
I tried :

```
'valueField' => ['name', 'first_name']
```

The output is `name;first_name` in my view.
The book only gives an example with a single field.
How can I format it to have `name first_name` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using a virtual field as CONCAT()? and then assign that to the value field? That would be the logical thing to do after all.

Comment: `valueField` parameters have to be columns name. The output is empty if I pass something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at virtual properties: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties.
Looking at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs could say you can use virtual properties.

Comment: That's it : I added the function `_getFullName()` given in the book, and updated `UsersTable` with `$this->displayField('full_name');`. You can't use `'valueField' => 'full_name'` in find. Thanks

Comment: Great! No problem, feel free to ask and thumb up :)